# Writing Kafka message headers using Logstash's Kafka output plugin

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash

I am looking to use Logstash's Kafka output plugin. This plugin allows us to post message to Kafka topic, but I don't see any configuration in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-kafka.html) that allows to post kafka message headers.

Thank you